# Display JSON Object to front end using services in Angular2

Tags: json, angular, user-interface

I have been trying to display a json file having multiple arrays in it on the front-end **div tag** in using Services **Angular2** using Typescript. Can anyone help?

Also, If anyone can help transforming this code by adding Model and Interface class would be very helpful.

Here is the code:

---

**SERVICE**

---

```
export class HttpServiceDemo{
    _data: any;

    private url: string = "assets/sample.json"
    constructor(private http: Http){}

    getMyOrder(){
        //return this.http.get(this.url)
                   // .map((response: Response)=> response.json());
                  return this.http.get(this.url)
                .map(res => this.http = res.json().myOrder);
    }

 }
```

---

**component.ts**

---

```
export class SimpleHTTPComponentComponent implements OnInit {

data:any;

Order_date:any;
OrderNumber: number;
P_O_Number:number;
Total: number;
Quote_Status: string;
Expiration_Date: any;
Quote_Created_On: any;

  constructor(public vara: HttpServiceDemo) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    //calling myorder from json
    this.vara.getMyOrder().subscribe(response => {
      this.data=response;

       for (var myOrder in this.data) 
      {
        console.log(myOrder, this.data[myOrder]);

        this.Order_date=this.data[myOrder].Order_Date;
        this.OrderNumber=this.data[myOrder].OrderNumber;
        this.P_O_Number=this.data[myOrder].P_O_Number;
        this.Total=this.data[myOrder].Total;
        this.Quote_Status=this.data[myOrder].Quote_Status;
      }
    })

}
```

---

**sample.json**
    ---------------

```
 {
        "accOrder":[
        {
            "Order_Date": "10-sep-1981",
            "OrderNumber" : "E12345",
            "P_O_Number": "P12345",
            "Total": "123",
            "Quote_Status": "In Progress"

        },
        {
           "Order_Date": "1-oct-1981",
            "OrderNumber" : "E82398",
            "P_O_Number": "P87815",
            "Total": "265",
            "Quote_Status": "In Progress"

        },
        {
            "Order_Date": "21-nov-1981",
            "OrderNumber" : "E52367",
            "P_O_Number": "P76549",
            "Total": "454",
            "Quote_Status": "In Progress"
        },
        {
            "Order_Date": "10-dec-1981",
            "OrderNumber" : "E42840",
            "P_O_Number": "P23632",
            "total": "123",
            "Quote_Status": "Completed"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: The data is visible in console using console.log statement in ngOnInit() but I can't figure out a way to display the same data to the front end.
Also, this is one such array, there are 'n' arrays in the json which need to be parsed and displayed

Comment: `I have been trying to display a json file having multiple arrays in it on the front-end div tag.` Can you please show what you have tried on your html file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-M250msv_fXbk5EYklWZGFteXM/view

Comment: before @Grégory answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying your console.log() shows the JSON just fine ?

Then, your data is correctly fetched into your component's data attribute.

You just have to go through your attribute in your template using *ngFor directive then.

Plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/4IdV3OHyNFNi90KXQQHP?p=preview

```
template: `
    <div>
      <div *ngFor="let order of data.accOrder" style="border: 1px solid lightgrey; padding: 15px; margin: 5px 0;">
    Order_Date : {{ order.Order_Date }} <br>
    OrderNumber : {{ order.OrderNumber }} <br>
    P_O_Number : {{ order.P_O_Number }} <br>
    Total : {{ order.Total }} <br>
    Quote_Status : {{ order.Quote_Status }} <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
```

PS : No need for your "for" loop inside ngOnInit() , this is not how you should access the data.

You should check out the [ngFor doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html) to learn more about it.

**EDIT :**

As I said in my comment below, my previous Plunker was using raw data while you use asynchronous data in your use case (it's coming from an Observable sent from your service).

To make it work then, you have to check if your component already received the data before you try to display it. For that, you need to use the *ngIf directive.

New Plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/W5qykrh4blplGxTyp8aC?p=preview

```
template: `
  <div *ngIf="data; else loading">
    <div *ngFor="let order of data.accOrder" style="border: 1px solid lightgrey; padding: 15px; margin: 5px 0;">
      Order_Date : {{ order.Order_Date }} <br>
      OrderNumber : {{ order.OrderNumber }} <br>
      P_O_Number : {{ order.P_O_Number }} <br>
      Total : {{ order.Total }} <br>
      Quote_Status : {{ order.Quote_Status }} <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ng-template #loading>Fetching the data from the webservice... Wait 3 seconds !</ng-template>
`,
```

You have to create a parent div to the one with your **ngFor* directive. In this parent div, use the **ngIf="data"* directive. Everything inside it will not be displayed until there is some data into the *data* attribute.

I used here an *if/else* syntax which appeared with Angular4. But you don't need that. That's just here to display a message while there is no data. It could be a loading spinner for example, to let the user know he has to wait.

If you don't want to use this if/else condition, you can do it without it like that :

```
template: `
  <div *ngIf="data">
    <div *ngFor="let order of data.accOrder" style="border: 1px solid lightgrey; padding: 15px; margin: 5px 0;">
      Order_Date : {{ order.Order_Date }} <br>
      OrderNumber : {{ order.OrderNumber }} <br>
      P_O_Number : {{ order.P_O_Number }} <br>
      Total : {{ order.Total }} <br>
      Quote_Status : {{ order.Quote_Status }} <br>
    </div>
  </div>
`,
```

Hope this helped :)

Comment: while i am using your template code exactly in the html file; i am getting an error **ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'accOrder' of undefined** whereas it is working fyn in the plunker files :(

Comment: HTML File: 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-M250msv_fXVUx2ZDYwa1d1MjA/view?usp=sharing

Error:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-M250msv_fXQU5uZ0NEbGZPZEk

Comment: Yes, that's because you receive your data from a service, using Observables, which mean you receive your data **asynchronously**.
In my Plunkr, it was just some raw data, which mean it was **synchronous**.
While your data is being loaded from your service, your component already tries to display the template. But it has no data yet into the "data" attribute, this is why it is _undefined_. Let me update my answer to make it work.

Comment: @YatinKapur Updated my post with the working template!

Comment: Thanks @Grégory Gossart